# How I can make alias called when it's called by a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

I added an alias:

```
$ alias anyalias="echo kallel"
```

If I execute:

```
$ anyalias
kallel
```

it executes the `echo` command without any problem.

Now, if I define a variable in this way:

```
$ var="anyalias"
```

and then execute with this way:

```
$  $var
-ash: anyalias: not found
```

Then I got a shell error.

How I can make `$var` running the command defined in the `anyalias` alias?

I m not looking to change the way of calling `$var`. But I m looking for a way of changing the definition of the alias or export it.

Comment: "I look to change the alias definition and not the call of $var". You can't, `alias` doesn't work that way.

Comment: @msw In fact my real question is: I want to post execute a script when I call the ls command. So I add an alias ls: `alias ls="/root/myscript.sh; ls"`. this alias will be exexute successfully whne I called it directly. but if I called wil a variable then it will not be executed as I expected

Comment: This question has been superceded by this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27193033/7552

Answer (score 6):

Instead of alias consider using function:

```
anyfunc() { echo "kallel"; }
v=anyfunc
$v
kallel
```

Safer is to store the call of function in an array (will store arguments also, if needed):

```
var=(anyfunc)
"${var[@]}"
kallel
```

Comment: I look tochange the alias definition and not the call of $var.

Comment: In that case simply give your function same name i.e. `anyalias() { echo "kallel"; }` Then same `var` definition will work.

Answer (score 2):

That's because **alias expansion** is performed previous to **parameter expansion**:
[Command-line Processing](http://hi.baidu.com/zhujian0805/item/dd92b035f51a80c32f8ec272)

[image]

As you can see, you can go through the process again with `eval`, which is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead/17529221).
Instead, you can use some alternatives as the one by @anubhava.

---

#### Example

```
$ alias anyalias="echo kallel"
$ var=anyalias
$ $var
bash: anyalias: command not found
$ eval $var
kallel
```

Again, use `eval` carefully. It's just to illustrate the expansion process.