# How to add a script call to a linux command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

I want to add in my linux system a script call to the `ls` command. This script should be executed each time the user execute the `ls` command.

I tried 2 solutions but both are limited:

1) Using **alias**

```
alias ls="/root/myscript.sh; ls"
```

But this solution is limited because the user can call `ls` via a variable in this way

```
var="ls"
$var
```

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191119/how-i-can-make-alias-called-when-its-called-by-a-varible) for more details

2) Using **function**

I create a function with the name `ls`:

```
ls() { /root/myscript.sh; /bin/ls $@ }
```

But this solution is limited because the user can call `ls` in this way:

```
/bin/ls
```

Are there another solution?

Comment: To avoid recursion, change your function to `ls() { /root/myscript.sh; command ls "$@"; }`

Comment: Check [PROMPT_COMMAND](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could always rename `/bin/ls` to `/bin/something` and create a shell script for `/bin/ls` and call the original there.

**But be warned**
this can easly brick your system.

Comment: If you do not alter `/bin/ls`, there is no way to prevent the user from invoking `/bin/ls` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a script `ls` say in `${HOME}/myls/ls` and then set the path variable to `${HOME}/myls:$PATH`

Comment: same problem of (2). I mean this solution is limited when the user call ls with `/bin/ls`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Mohamed, you are right, but you're asking as if the person from which you want to prevent running LS directly, knows more about the OS than you do ? If that is the case, copy your custom script to /bin/ls ... if that is the kind of level we are talking here. Don't forget to convert your script into a binary file, and use touch to set the date to the date of what /bin/ls now has, so that it doesn't stand out between the other commands.